# Correct CSS-selector in Click Element (GTM trigger)

Tags: css, triggers, google-tag-manager

I am lost with getting a trigger to fire for all menu items on my site. As there is no Class element given I try to do the check with the Click Element field (. But any part of it I try I get a mismatch in GTM preview mode.

Can anyone tell me what would be valid CSS selector for that trigger?

Click Element for menu item "Kontakt" is

```
https://www.deutschland-greeter.de/kontakt/: html.js > body.home.page-template-default.page.page-id-39.et_pb_button_helper_class.et_fixed_nav.et_show_nav.et_primary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade.et_secondary_nav_dropdown_animation_fade.et_header_style_left.et_pb_footer_columns1.et_cover_background.et_pb_gutter.windows.et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_pagebuilder_layout.et_no_sidebar.et_divi_theme.et-db.chrome > div.et-animated-content#page-container > header.et-fixed-header#main-header > div.container.clearfix.et_menu_container > div#et-top-navigation > div#et_mobile_nav_menu > div.mobile_nav.closed > ul.et_mobile_menu#mobile_menu > li.testclass.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-1094#menu-item-1094 > a
```

One of the matches I tried is `div.container.clearfix.et_menu_container`

Thanks a lot!

Klaus

Comment: You could use an "just links" trigger and set the filter condition to {{Click Url}} equals (url of the link). That might be simpler than fiddling with CSS selectors.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to track all menu-clicks with one trigger.

Comment: The clicked element will always be the "a" tag (because that is the innermost tag), so you could always try something as simple as "{{Click Element}} css selector matches .menu.item a".

Comment: Thanks, Eike, that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both desktop and mobile Kontakt in the main menu:

```
li#menu-item-1094>a[href="https://www.deutschland-greeter.de/kontakt/"]
```

If you want to have it for every a on the page that leads to /kontakt/ (like what you have in the footer), use this:

```
a[href="https://www.deutschland-greeter.de/kontakt/"]
```

I would go with the first option.

Here's a variant that will catch all top menu clicks for desktop:

```
ul#top-menu>li>a
```

Keep in mind that using CSS selectors for tracking (also referred to as DOM scraping) is ultimately not reliable since front-end devs won't keep your tracking in mind when they update the site.

Comment: Sorry, I was unprecise. I would like to track all menu clicks in one fly, not single menu-items

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to catch only top level clicks.